# How to add an 'apt' linked application into Firefox?

Tags: apt, firefox, apturl

- Just installed Ubuntu 17.10.
- `aptitude` and `apturl` are installed

But when I click on apt links, the only message I get is 'this address doesn't exist'. Firefox doesn't ask me which application must be used to open such a link.

My question is : how do I make the link between Firefox and `apturl` (since Firefox doesn't ask me what to do)?

Comment: `apt-url` is installed? There is [no command named `apt-url`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=apt-url) nor [a package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/apt-url).

Comment: @muru I was wondering what that does!

Comment: with `apt search` I don't see that app, so please make your issue more understandable!

Comment: I think OP meant `apturl`.

Comment: If you find my answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it. And please delete your "answer" since it's just a "thank you" comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Firefox and type `about:config` in the address-bar and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. ("*Accept the risk*" if needed.)
2. Right click anywhere and select *New > Boolean*.
3. Enter `network.protocol-handler.expose.apt` for preference name and select `false` for value.
4. Restart Firefox.
5. Try opening an `apt://` link. It should show a pop-up, select *AptUrl*, and check the option to remember it.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6K2F2n5mmU)